# How to fix tsc-watch restarts when test file uploading?

Tags: file, nestjs, tsc

I want to test file uploading API locally in my NestJS project. I have followed [this doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload). However, when I uploaded files the `tsc-watch` restart since the `upload` folder is changed.

Here I am using `NestJS` version 6 and everything installed from `nest-cli`. I am also using Google Cloud Storage to store the files. I test the project locally by running `yarn start:dev`.

I have tried adding `upload` folder in `exclude` option in both `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.build.json` but it does not work.

I have also tried using `nodemon`. Unfortunately, `nodemon` does not restart when I make change to the code.

Here are some codes ([repo here](https://github.com/UtopiaBeam/cgrader-backend)):

### controller

```
    @Patch(':id/file')
    @UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor('file', { dest: join(__dirname, '../../upload') }),
    )
    async uploadProblem(
        @UploadedFile() file: FileDto,
        @Param('id') id: string,
    ) {
        if (file) {
            await this.service.uploadProblem(id, file);
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestException('No files uploaded');
        }
    }
```

### service

```
    async uploadProblem(id: string, file: FileDto) {
        const problem = await this.findById(id);
        await this.fileService.uploadFile(`${problem.code}/problem`, file);
    }
```

### `fileService`

```
    async uploadFile(name: string, file: FileDto) {
        await this.bucket.upload(file.path, {
            destination: name,
            contentType: file.mimetype,
            resumable: false,
        });
        removeSync(file.path);
    }
```

### `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start:dev": "tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess \"node dist/main.js\"",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^3.3.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^6.1.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.10.1",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/express": "4.16.1",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.11",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.19",
    "@types/node": "11.13.4",
    "@types/supertest": "2.0.7",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "supertest": "4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.2",
    "ts-node": "8.1.0",
    "tsc-watch": "2.2.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "3.8.0",
    "tslint": "5.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.3"
  },
  ...
}
```

I expect the file to be uploaded and deleted afterward, but `tsc-watch` keeps restarting and never upload nor delete the file.

Is there anyway to stop `tsc-watch` from restart when `upload` directory is changed, or is there any other tools should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution, using `ts-lint` is to move the `upload` folder outside the `src` folder and ignore that folder.

Another solution is the same as you suggest, using `nodemon` with `ts-node`, but `nodemon` itself has the problem of watching files inside `docker` and change start command to the following.

```
"start": "nodemon -L --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec ts-node src/main.ts",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set to ignore watch in package.json

```
"watch": {
    "ignore": "upload"
  }
```